# Will QWizard delete QWizardPage or will it leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

If I have `QWizard`, and I instantiate this without specifying parent, will it delete its pages when it goes out of scope or will they leak?

```
{
WelcomeWizard wiz;
wiz.addPage(new QWizardPage);
}
```

I think `QWizard` will delete them however I would really appreciate any more detailed explanation.

Comment: It will delete it when the parent (WelcomeWizard) is deleted.

Comment: even if I didn't specify parent explicite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWizard::addPage` internally calls [setPage](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/239fe290ad241aac3d6b86ce598f679a0a72fd11:src/widgets/dialogs/qwizard.cpp#L2204), which calls `page->setParent(...)` as one of the first things done.

So yes, the wizard does take ownership of the pages, and they will be subject to normal `QObject` lifetimes. Deleting the wizard will delete all of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Qt automatically deletes the child of a widget when the parent is deleting

Comment: thank you very much, however this is clear, the question being what if I have QWizard, and I instantiate this without specifying parent